# How to invalidate and revalidate custom claims in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a simple method that will add a custom claim. This method is called outside of login.

```
Claim claim = new Claim("SomeCustomClaim", "Test123", ClaimValueTypes.String);
var result = await _userManager.AddClaimAsync((ApplicationUser)user, claim);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    //do something
}
```

Edited:
I'm trying to accomplish the followings:

1. When the user logs out, it should remove the custom claims.
2. When the user closes the browser and clear the cookies and cache, it should remove the custom claims.
3. At certain interval, it should revalidate the claims.

I have tried the followings:

Attempt 1:
`await _signInManager.SignOutAsync()` does not do anything at all. Once the user logs back in, somehow the claims are being added back even though I did not call the AddClaim again.

Attempt 2:
I explicitly called the `RemoveClaimAsync()` on log out. While this solve #1, it requires the user to actually click the log out button. If the user merely closes the browser, the claims will persist.

Attempt 3:
I added the following codes in the startup.cs:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
});
```

This appears to completely invalidate the cookies. However, as soon as the user logs back in again, somehow the claims persist without calling the AddClaim.

And I haven't figured out how to revalidate the claims at certain interval.

Comment: Not quite. I edited my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `await _userManager.AddClaimAsync()` to Store the claim in the table `AspNetUserCliams` , So the claim not only in cookie , but also in database. When you log out , The code just remove the claim in cookie. if you want to remove all the custom claims, you also need to remove the claim in database.

When user close the browser and clear the cookies and cache , Once user logs back in , he may be read the claims in database. So you can delete the claims in database and try to log in again to check if the claims can be added back.